# Cannot get difference between two timestamps

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want return the number of dates which have a difference less than 30 minutes. These are the records stored in the database:

```
id | last_login
0    2019-02-11 17:22:47
1    0000-00-00 00:00:00
2    2019-02-11 17:22:03
3    0000-00-00 00:00:00
4    0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

the result of the query should be 2, but I get 1:

```
$time = strtotime('+30 minutes');

return $this->db->select('COUNT(last_login) AS users_online')
    ->from('login')
    ->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login) < ' . $time)
    ->get()->num_rows();
```

Comment: Because there is only one row. You need to get the field value from the result set.

Comment: @JonStirling I have 5 rows, I'm missing something?

Comment: Your DATABASE has 5 rows,  but 1 row is returned by your SELECT.

Comment: You're using `COUNT()` and `num_rows`. You need to either return the value of your count, or remove the count from the select and just return the num_rows;

Comment: Unrelated to the question: this query seems weird to me. Surely last_login should never be in the future, right?

Comment: @Peter so what's the solution?

Comment: What all the other commenters already said. Aggregation functions such as COUNT return only one row.

Comment: @Peter I tried Scoots solution but return a wrong number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code here. The first, is you are cutting everything down to 1 record with an implicit group thanks to `count()` - and then getting the number of records returned via `num_rows()`.

The second issue is you are getting every single record in the table where the last login is less than 30 minutes in the future... Which will always be every row.

```
echo date('H:i') . "\n" . date('H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes'));
```

Yields:

```
16:38
17:08
```

Comment: How to implement this in the query?

Comment: Change `$time = strtotime('+30 minutes');` to `$time = strtotime('-30 minutes');`, and change `COUNT(last_login) AS users_online` to `last_login`. This is then returning a count of all logins prior to (current time minus 30 minutes).

Comment: your solution return 1